# wpf Binding display path to datagrid in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a datagrid which binds a TimeSlotsPerday, this is a list of items.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSlotsPerDay}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" cal:Message.Attach="[Event CellEditEnding]=[Action SaveChanges($this)]">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="AmountDisplayStyle">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MaxAmountOptimizationOrders}" />
            </Style>                
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="AmountEditStyle">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding MaxAmountOptimizationOrders}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Day}" Header="Dag" Width="Auto"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The TimeSlotsPerday contains another list of TimeSlots which are binden this way.

```
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30 * i);
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = t.ToString() };
        var binding = new Binding($"TimeSlots[{i}]");
        col.ElementStyle = (Style)Grid.Resources["AmountDisplayStyle"];
        col.EditingElementStyle = (Style)Grid.Resources["AmountEditStyle"];
        col.Binding = binding;
        Grid.Columns.Add(col);
    }
```

My problem with this setup is, that the grid should display an item `MaxAmountOptimizationOrders` inside a Timeslot.

But if i add this to the binding, editing becomes impossible, since i need the id in the dto.

I tried to set it using elementstyle but this doesn't seem to work.

**So my question is**

How can i set the `displaypath` to the right value ?

And how to send the new value and id back through the caliburn micro method ?

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event CellEditEnding]=[Action SaveChanges($this)]
```